# How to get authors who have added the post in the specific custom post type

Tags: plugins, theme-development, list-authors

I have a custom post called `event` and I have to show all the authors who have added the post. I have tried the below code but I am getting all the users on the page.

For example. There are 4 users called A, B, C, and D on the website and A and B added the post.

Now I have to get only A and B  users but below code getting all the users like A,B,C,D

Any idea how to get the user to add the post in the event post type.

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID','display_name' ),'order' => 'ASC', 'who' =>'authors' ));

    foreach ($users as $user){
    $userid=$user->ID;
    //echo  $post_count = count_user_posts($userid);
    echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url(get_author_posts_url($userid)).'">'.$user->display_name.'</a></li>';
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "who have added the post", are you meaning all users who have written at least 1 post of the event post type? If so, you can get all the authors of all events like so:

```
$event_posts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'event', // Or whatever your event post type is
    'numberposts' => -1,
]);

// Get all the author (user) IDs of all events
$event_author_ids = wp_list_pluck( $event_posts, 'post_author' );

// Now get all the user objects
$users = get_users([
    'include' => $event_author_ids,
]);
```

Alternatively, if you are meaning the author of the *current* event post, there can only ever be one author per-post, and you can just use [the author template tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) whilst in [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).

```
echo get_the_author_link();
// Get author <a /> HTML

echo get_the_author_meta( $prop );
// Get author property e.g. display_name, user_email, first_name etc.
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried the first solution and it's working.. just want to know why you have used the include in the get_users

Comment: Check the [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_User_Query/prepare_query/) docs. The `include` param is for getting users (authors) by their ID (which is the post authors of any event post).